# Python BeautifulSoup trouble extracting titles from a page with JS

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having some serious issues trying to extract the titles from a webpage. I've done this before on some other sites but this one seems to be an issue because of the Javascript.

The test link is "https://www.thomasnet.com/products/adhesives-393009-1.html"

The first title I want extracted is "Toagosei America, Inc."

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ("https://www.thomasnet.com/products/adhesives-393009-1.html")

r = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

print(soup.get_text())
```

Now if I run it like this, with get_text, i can find the titles in the result, however as soon as I change it to find_all or find, the titles are lost. I cant find them using web browser's inspect tool, because its all JS generated.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in question you should show how you use `find()` and `find_all()` - it could explain why you don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify what to find, in this case `<h2>` to get first title:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.thomasnet.com/products/adhesives-393009-1.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

first_title = soup.find('h2')
print(first_title.text)
```

Prints:

```
Toagosei America, Inc.
```

Comment: Thank you. I for some reason was having a hard time figuring out which HTML tag it was. Would this process work with a for loop to get all of the h2 titles?

Comment: @Kevin You can use `soup.find_all('h2')` to return all `<h2>` titles in soup.

Comment: got it to work with     "for i in soup.find_all('h2'): print(i.text)"